# apache mysql - "#08S01Got packets out of order"

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I just installed xampp, I worked with apache and MySQL to get data for java, suddenly apache had shutdown, so I reconfigure the ports of apache(8383) and MySQL(8080) to this is what I get

## 08S01Got packets out of order

any one had any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of the port for mysql? i usually set 3306

Comment: it's not a question of ports, because I get a result but a wrong one, to be sure , I changed MySQL port to 3306 and a refresh the page and I got the same result: “#08S01Got packets out of order”

Comment: however it might be something related to your .ini config. Try this https://www.ryadel.com/en/fix-mysql-server-gone-away-packets-order-similar-mysql-related-errors/